# DataFrame pivot_table sum returning zero on some columns when there is data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
|id|name|start_date|clicks|conversions|installs|downloads|
|--|----|----------|------|-----------|--------|-----------|
|101|India|2023-06-06|1|4|0|NaN|
|101|India|2023-06-06|2|5|0|NaN|
|101|India|2023-06-06|1|6|0|NaN|
|201|Kenya|2023-09-15|5|8|0|NaN|
|201|Kenya|2023-09-15|2|1|0|NaN|
|201|NaN|NaN|NaN|NaN|NaN|10|
|201|NaN|NaN|NaN|NaN|NaN|5|
|201|NaN|NaN|NaN|NaN|NaN|4|
```

My code is this:

```py
    pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(
        df,
        index=['id','name','start_date'],
        aggfunc={'clicks': 'sum','conversions': 'sum','installs': 'sum', 'downloads': 'sum'})
```

And the output is:

```
|id|name|start_date|clicks|conversions|installs|downloads|
|--|----|----------|------|-----------|--------|-----------|
|101|India|2023-06-06|4|15|0|0|
|201|Kenya|2023-09-15|7|9|0|0|
```

The output is I *expected* to get

```
|id|name|start_date|clicks|conversions|installs|downloads|
|--|----|----------|------|-----------|--------|-----------|
|101|India|2023-06-06|4|15|0|0|
|201|Kenya|2023-09-15|7|9|0|19|
```

The sum of conversions comes out 0 and not 19.  What have I done incorrectly?

Comment: Does a given id always have a single name and start_date (or NaN), if not, can you provide an updated example?

Comment: Yes, an id always has the same name and start date.

Comment: OK, then a `groupby.agg` is what you need.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add your data in a [reproducible format](/q/20109391/16343464) (as **code**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want a `pivot_table` but rather a [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
out = (df.groupby('id', as_index=False)
         .agg({'name': 'first',
               'start_date': 'first',
               'clicks': 'sum',
               'conversions': 'sum',
               'installs': 'sum',
               'downloads': 'sum'})
      )
```

Output:

```
    id   name  start_date  clicks  conversions  installs  downloads
0  101  India  2023-06-06     4.0         15.0       0.0        0.0
1  201  Kenya  2023-09-15     7.0          9.0       0.0       19.0
```

Comment: Ok, so @mozway with the change, what happens is instead of rows 0 and 1 in your answer, I get a row 3 which has  id=201, and the downloads is there with the total I am looking for. All the other values in that 3rd row are blank or 0.  Why did it create a new row?

Comment: I added a foolow up question for this here:  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77629826/pandas-dataframe-groupby-agg-adding-an-extra-row-for-a-sum-value-inste

Comment: As explained in the other question, `agg` shouldn't yield three rows (unless you have three different IDs). It's difficult to know exactly what's going on since your example is not reproducible, but most likely you have a mix of `201` (integer) and `"201"` (string). Or maybe all strings but dangling spaces. Try `df['id'] = df['id'].astype(str).str.strip()` to have homogeneous IDs.

Comment: Thanks @mozway! I deleted the other question.  I bet you are right - the dataframe was created by concatenating two other dataframes, and somehow the id's must be different.  Thanks for your help, support, and tips.  This is solved.

Comment: Final follow-up - It was a type mismatch on some of the data due to the concatenated dataframe - you were spot on.  Everything works great now.